# Unable to Connect to SQL Server Database using ASP.NET Webservice

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I have a website and a webservice. Both uses same Data Access Layer. Both uses same connection string to connect to SQL Server 2008. But my website is able to connect to the database but webservice throws following exception:

> Server was unable to process request. ---> System.Exception: System.Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.

Other then verifying the connection string/network level stuff, is there any "out of the box" error that might cause this issue?

Database: SQL Server 2008
OS: Windows Server 2008 R2
.NET Framework: 2.0

Comment: are they both hosted on the same box?

Comment: do they both connect remotely to the server?

Comment: Have you turned On TCP-IP Protocols ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the web server and DB server are on two different boxed. First ensure that external connections are permitted by the SQL server, then ensure that the port is open between the two server (you can do this using telnet).

Comment: You mean remote connections are not on ?

Comment: Not by default, you have to activate them within the SQL configuration manager. Within the Configuration Manager, go to "SQL Server Network Configuration" and ensure that "TCP/IP" or "Named Pipes" is set to enabled (you'll probably need TCP/IP).